# How to implement phonetic and non-phonetic search without using DatastaxEnterpriseSearch in c#

Tags: c#, search, cassandra, full-text-search

In every specific language the "sound" of a name it's not very unique to search precisely (e.g.  Schmid, Schmied, Schmidt or Meyer, Meier, Mayer) or to identify the user
and nike names are often used in every spoken language (e.g. Päschä means Peter in Swiss German)
So, I have to implement also phonetic and non-phonetic search in `Cassandra` using `c#`. But i don't want to use `DataStaxEnterpriseSearch` ? you know it is very costly.

Please help me, How can i do it.

Thanks

Comment: You can use Solr in Separate Cluster and search from that.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Could i use solr without  DSE (DataStaxEnterpriseSearch) ?

Comment: Yes. you can. but you have to build a tools to maintain data synchronization between cassandra and solr.